# Create a nested url structure in wordpress for custom categories

Tags: wordpress, url, nested, categories

I am working on a website in wordpress. I have to show some products which fall under various categories. For Example:

1. Apparel

   1. Women

      1. Tops
      2. Bottoms
      3. Footwear
   2. Men

      1. Shirts
      2. Bottoms
      3. Footwear
   3. Kids

      1. Shirts
      2. Bottoms
      3. Toys

Now I want the URL Structure to be like  :

www.mysite.com/apparel/women/tops  for the categories

and If I open a product like abc under the above category , the url should be:

www.mysite.com/apparel/women/tops/abc  for the categories

Can anyone please help me in creating the custom categories such that I can get the above url structure with proper pagination.

Thanks

Comment: Are you adding Products using WordPress posts or using plugins?

Comment: No I am not using any plugins. I tried to create custom post type and taxonomy. But that does not give me exactly what I require. I can paste my code here if you want to go through it.

Comment: Try this:
Create a category structure like you have mentioned above with Category and Sub-Category, then add your products in different categories. Goto Sttings->Permalink->Common Settings->Custom Structure and insert in the field "%category%"  then Save Changes

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solid answer but

You can fake it with

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-no-category-base/

and changing permalink structure to /%category%/%postname%/

By faking it I mean. That the URL will look like:

www.mysite.com/apparel/women/tops/productName

but actually it can be whatever

www.mysite.com/whatever/whatever/productName

I hope somebody knows a better answer. But a few months back I was searching for a similar thing, but did not find a solution.

Comment: Thank you for your response AKU Sven. I will try this but it would be great if someone can provide a solution without plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Nested Pages](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-nested-pages/) plugin.  It adds a "drag and drop" interface to the page manager page in the admin dashboard (similar to the drag and drop in Menus).